# Views pager with anchor on another page?

Tags: views, paging, navigation

I'm creating a page that have two sections, one with an image, as a "presentation", and other at the bottom that has a list, created with a View. That list have pagers created with the "Views Simple Pager" module(https://www.drupal.org/project/views_simple_pager), and that view is within a section markup in the page.

The problem now is that when I change the page of the view, from page 1 to page 2, for example, the whole page is refreshed and it goes again to the top, where I have the image and not the list. I would like to customize the pager in some way that permits me to go directly to the views section, something like "mypage.com/News?page=2#views-section" instead of "mypage.com/News?page=2".

Is it possible? Thanks.